# Sql query result directly in the excel cells

Tags: sql, vba, export, excel-2007

I have joined in QA team and need to create a excel sheet who is very smart so to fulfill that first i run query in sql and copy result and paste in the excel.I need to remove this time so what i need:
1.Query runs automatically on remote SQL Server using correct database
2.Results are exported directly in my desired cells.
3.Query result for example SUM_AMOUNT,COUNT(NAME) ,Total(Salary) etc. pasted in desired cells.

Please advise if any macro or any other functionality that can do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. When you say copy that query and paste in excel...Do you mean you copy the results of the query and paste in excel or paste the query in excel?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion ..new to this.I actually mean I paste result of that query in the excel in my desired cells (where i have created a format) so can this be done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to do this is through BIDS which is Business Intelligence Development Studio(BIDS) or more recently called SQL SERVER DATA TOOLS (SSDT).

All you have to do is open excel> save as anything and save it anywhere.(You will use this in the connection manager in SSIS)

Then go to BIDS and create an Integration Services project.
Pull a Data Flow Task.
Add OLEDB/SQL Server Source.
Add an Excel Destination.
Add an OLEDB connection manager and an excel connection manager to point to the locations that they exists and run the ssis package.
Thats it. Everytime you run the package, your results will be in your excel.
(Keeping in mind that you create a new excel and change the connection manager to point to the new one. Now this is an explanation of how it can be done. But you could play around with it and you can do anything with it even using a single excel file)

More information on BIDS found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767(v=sql.105).aspx

Another way to get the data using Excel itself to connect to SQL SERVER : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-import-sql-server-data-HA010342298.aspx

[Here's a perfect example to show you how it is done](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJI6pPueyzM)

Comment: Thanks for this ,I do not have access to BIDS but will try to have this.But I will always be using one excel template to extract data and will not use new file.so my expectation from SSDT are :1.It extract result in my desire cells after some command or package2. My template starts working as its fetching values from those cells.3.Excel template dashboard view is perfect .....so if I use new file its no use for me as I will have to again copy paste same in the excel template.

Comment: Then you might have to do a CTRL+A...Delete the info on that sheet and re-run the ssis package.That should do.

Comment: @Gouri: Please see the updated answer which shows you exactly how it is done. Please upvote or select this as answer if it resolves your issue. Thank you.